# Firebase dynamic links. How to delete custom subdomain for page.link

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have created a custom subdomain for firebase dynamic links in my project like
`somedomain.page.link`, 
but i want to delete it and use this subdomain in another firebase project.
Is it possible to delete it?

Answer (score 2):

The Dynamic Links console now has a "Delete domain" option in the menu that's next to the "New Dynamic Link" button.

To use a subdomain in a different project, you'll need to delete it in the current project, wait 30 days (the delete dialogue warns about this wait time), and then claim it in your other Firebase project.